# Compatibility between Hammer.js and Phonegap on Nexus7 and Nexus4

Tags: javascript, events, cordova, hammer.js

I'm playing with the version 1.0.5 of Hammer.js on an Android App with Phonegap 2.8.1.

On the iPad everything seems to be ok.
But on the Nexus7 and Nexus4 (Android 4.2.2) swipe and tap with more than 1 finger does not work.

Here is my test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            #touch-me {
                width:500px;
                height:500px;
                background:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="touch-me">gf</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var hammertime = Hammer(document.getElementById('touch-me'), {
                swipe_max_touches: 5
            });
            hammertime.on("swipe", function(e) {
                alert('SWIPE:'+e.gesture.touches.length);
            });
            hammertime.on("tap", function(e) {
                alert('TAP:'+e.gesture.touches.length);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I do a two finger tap, it alerts `SWIPE:1` it's like Hammer interprets the two points as a move.